# Help understand chain rule derivative

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I was verifying a larger function derivative on wolfram alpha and came across this derivative:

$\frac{d}{dx} (1-x)^2 = 2(x -1)$

Using the chain rule, I was expecting to get:

$2(1 - x)$

Instead. I trust wolfram alpha can differentiate better than me, so what am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You actually didn't use the chain rule correctly: To use the chain rule, you need to also multiply $2(1 - x)$ by  $\frac d{dx}(1 - x)= -1$.

In other words, we have $$f(x) = (1 - x)^2 \implies f'(x) = 2(1 - x)\cdot \frac{d}{dx}(1 - x) = -2(1 - x) = 2(x - 1)$$

Comment: Thanks, I mistakenly thought the derivative of 1-x was 1 instead of -1.

Comment: Not a problem. I presumed it was a simple lapse of thought involved here.

Comment: @amWhy: Could use another UV +1

Answer (score 0):

In more detail:
$$
\frac{d\left[(1-x)^2\right]}{dx}
 = 2 (1-x) \frac{d[1-x]}{dx}
 = 2 (1-x) (-1)
 = 2 (x-1).
$$

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{d (1-x)^2}{dx}  =2(1-x) \frac{d (1-x)}{dx}=2(1-x)(-1)=2(x-1)$